# Игра паззл и проблемы с таймером.

Tags: таймер, java

Здравствуйте.
Вот код:

```
package final_project;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class window {

    private JPanel pn, pn2;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel text;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private JButton mas[][] = new JButton[4][4];
    private JButton buf, buf2 = null;
    private int id[][] = new int[4][4];
    private int i = 0, j = 0, bufi = 0, bufj = 0, c = 0, gi = 0, gj = 0, check = 0, time = 60, points = 0, record = 0;
    private boolean fl = false;
    MouseAdapter mouse;
    ActionListener atimer;
    /*
     Смотрим на javax.swing.Timer. Пример: import javax.swing.Timer;
     //Будет вызываться каждую секунду
     timer= new Timer( 1000 , new ActionListener(
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
     System.out.println( "WOW!" );
     }
     ));
     timer.start();

     */

    public window(int t, int p) {
        //Считать рекорд.
        time = t;
        points = p;
        newid();
        frame = new JFrame("Игра для даунов.");
        frame.setBounds(400, 400, 400, 450);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        pn = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        pn2 = new JPanel();
        pn2.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 30);
        pn.setBounds(0, 30, 400, 400);
        text = new JLabel("Рекорд:" + record + "Время:0:" + time + "Очки: " + points);
        text.setSize(400, 10);
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, atimer);
        atimer = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.out.println('1');
                time--;
                if (time == 0) {
                    frame.dispose();
                    if (points > record) {
                        //Вписать рекорд.   
                    }
                }
            }
        };  
        mouse = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                check = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                        if (!mas[i][j].isEnabled()) {
                            check++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (check == 15) {
                    points++;
                    frame.dispose();
                    new window(time, points);
                }
                buf = (JButton) e.getSource();
                if (!buf.equals(buf2)) {
                    c++;
                    for (i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                        for (j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                            if (mas[i][j].equals(((JButton) e.getSource()))) {
                                gi = i;
                                gj = j;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("i=" + gi + "j=" + gj + "c=" + c + "check" + check + "time" + time + "points" + points);
                    if (c % 2 == 1) {
                        buf.setEnabled(false);
                        bufi = gi;
                        bufj = gj;
                        buf2 = buf;
                    } else {
                        buf.setEnabled(false);
                        //System.out.println("ij=" + i + j + "bufij=" + bufi + bufj + "c=" + c);
                        //System.out.println("id=" + i+" "+j + "bufid=" + bufi+" "+bufj + "c=" + c);
                        if (id[gi][gj] == id[bufi][bufj]) {
                            System.out.println('1');
                        } else {
                            buf.setEnabled(true);
                            buf2.setEnabled(true);
                            buf2 = buf;
                        }
                    }
                    pn.updateUI();
                }
            }
        };

        for (i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = new JButton();
                mas[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon("src\\images\\" + id[i][j] + ".png"));
                pn.add(mas[i][j]);
                mas[i][j].addMouseListener(mouse);

            }
        }
        pn2.add(text);
        frame.add(pn2);
        frame.add(pn);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void newid() {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < id[i].length; j++) {
                do {
                    a = r.nextInt(4);
                    b = r.nextInt(4);
                } while (id[a][b] != 0);
                id[a][b] = i + 1;

            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(id[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в таймер не вызывает свою функцию тика.Как можно решить проблему?
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сначала определить aTimer, а затем создавать timer, иначе у вас получается что вы в таймер передаёте null, а затем создаете aTimer.

```
atimer = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                System.out.println('1');
                time--;
                if (time == 0) {
                    frame.dispose();
                    if (points > record) {
                        //Вписать рекорд.   
                    }
                }
            }
        };  
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, atimer);
```